# How to change the background color of an entire Linear layout in android that contains textviews

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this project I'm working on and I have a LinearLayout that contains two TextViews. I have set the background color of the LinearLayout using the android:background = "@color/...", but this proper applies only upto where the textviews end. If it ends at the middle of the screen, then the color stops there and the rest going down displays white.
I do not understand. I have search thoroughly to no avail.
Please guys help me. Here is my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/gold">

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/gold"
  android:paddingBottom="10dp"
  android:paddingLeft="15dp"
  android:paddingTop="10dp"
  android:textSize="20sp" />

 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView2"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/gold"
  android:paddingLeft="15dp"
  android:paddingRight="10dp"
  android:textSize="15sp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your LinearLayout is probably only using wrap_content. If you want the full screen to be of that color, your LinearLayout must extends to use the full screen:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/my_color>

</LinearLayout>
```

If your LinearLayout is not the root element in your layout, then set the background to the root element, ensuring it has match_parent for both width and height.

Comment: My linear layout is the root element, and i have set the layout hight and width to match parent, but it is not still working.

Comment: If your LinearLayout used as a cell layout for a ListView? If so, set the background in your Listview, not on the cell itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think..the main LinearLayout's width is set to wrap_content.
Change it to match_parent.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/your_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   ....
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried it but it can't seem to help. I just added the layout file in the original post. Thanks for your usual support.

Comment: change the textview's height to wrap_content

Comment: Tried but same thing. Worth mentioning is that those textviews are populated using data from a database and the. The list is displayed using and custom list adapter. That part is working. I just need to change the color from white to gold. 

Thanks for your usual support.